# The asymptotic expansion of an integral of an exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

What is the asymptotic expansion of $f(x) := \int_0^1 e^{-x(1-u^2)}du$?

The integrand steeply declines near $u=1$. I tried to transform $u$ into something that is suitable for the method of steepest descent, but have not found an appropriate transformation. Integration by parts has not yield a satisfactory result, perhaps due to I having not found the right components to integrate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The minimum of $1-u^2$ occurs at $u=1$, and near there we have $1-u^2 \approx 2(1-u)$, which is linear in the quantity $1-u$. This suggests we make the change of variables $1-u^2 = v$ (which is linear in $v$), giving

$$
\int_0^1 e^{-x(1-u^2)}\,du = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} e^{-xv} (1-v)^{-1/2}\,dv.
$$

Then, following [Watson's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma), we can get the asymptotic expansion by expanding the subdominant term, $(1-v)^{-1/2}$, around $v=0$ and integrating term-by-term from $v=0$ to $v=\infty$:

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 e^{-x(1-u^2)}\,du &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} e^{-xv} (1-v)^{-1/2}\,dv \\
&\approx \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{-1/2}{k} (-1)^k \int_0^\infty e^{-xv} v^k\,dv \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{-1/2}{k} \frac{(-1)^k k!}{x^{k+1}}
\end{align}
$$

as $x \to \infty$, which matches the series given in [the other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2890622/5531).

---

Let's prove the special case of Watson's lemma we use in this answer. We'll assume that $g(v)$ is analytic at $v=0$ and that $\int_0^a \lvert g(v) \rvert\,dv$ exists (these are certainly true for $g(v) = (1-v)^{-1/2}$), and show that

$$
I(v) = \int_0^a e^{-xv}g(v)\,dv \approx \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{g^{(k)}(0)}{x^{k+1}}
$$

as $x \to \infty$. In other words, we will show that the asymptotic expansion for the integral can be obtained by expanding $g(v)$ in Taylor series around $v=0$ and integrating term-by-term.

Since $g(v)$ is analytic at $v=0$, there is a $\delta \in (0,a]$ such that $g^{(k)}(v)$ is analytic on $[0,\delta]$ for all $k$. Further, Taylor's theorem tells us that for any positive integer $N$ and any $v \in [0,\delta]$, there is a $v^* \in [0,v]$ for which

$$
g(v) = \sum_{k=0}^{N} \frac{g^{(k)}(0)}{k!} v^k + \frac{g^{(N+1)}(v^*)}{(N+1)!} v^{N+1}. \tag{1}
$$

We will split the integral $I(v)$ at this $\delta$, and estimate each piece separately. To this end, we define

$$
I(v) = \int_0^\delta e^{-xv}g(v)\,dv + \int_\delta^a e^{-xv}g(v)\,dv = I_1(v) + I_2(v).
$$

We only need a rough estimate on $I_2(v)$:

$$
\lvert I_2(v) \rvert \leq \int_\delta^a e^{-xv} \lvert g(v) \rvert \,dv \leq e^{-\delta x} \int_0^a \lvert g(v) \rvert\,dv,
$$

where we have assumed the last integral on the right is finite. Thus

$$
I(v) = I_1(v) + O(e^{-\delta x})
$$

as $x \to \infty$.

Now, from $(1)$ we have

$$
I_1(v) = \sum_{k=0}^{N} \frac{g^{(k)}(0)}{k!} \int_0^\delta e^{-xv} v^k \,dv + \frac{1}{(N+1)!} \int_0^\delta e^{-xv} g^{(N+1)}(v^*) v^{N+1}\,dv.
$$

The last integral can be bounded by

$$
\left\lvert \int_0^\delta e^{-xv} g^{(N+1)}(v^*) v^{N+1}\,dv \right\rvert \leq \left( \sup_{0 < v < \delta} \left\lvert g^{(N+1)}(v) \right\rvert \right) \int_0^\infty e^{-xv} v^{N+1}\,dv = \frac{\text{const.}}{x^{N+2}}.
$$

Thus

$$
I_1(v) = I_1(v) = \sum_{k=0}^{N} \frac{g^{(k)}(0)}{k!} \int_0^\delta e^{-xv} v^k \,dv + O\!\left(x^{-N-2}\right)
$$

as $x \to \infty$. Finally we reattach the tails to the integrals in the sum,

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\delta e^{-xv} v^k \,dv &= \int_0^\infty e^{-xv} v^k\,dv - \int_\delta^\infty e^{-xv} v^k\,dv \\
&= \frac{k!}{x^{k+1}} + O\!\left(e^{-\delta x}\right),
\end{align}
$$

and substitute these into the sum to get

$$
I_1(v) = \sum_{k=0}^{N} \frac{g^{(k)}(0)}{x^{k+1}} + O\!\left(x^{-N-2}\right)
$$

and hence

$$
I(v) = \sum_{k=0}^{N} \frac{g^{(k)}(0)}{x^{k+1}} + O\!\left(x^{-N-2}\right)
$$

as $x \to \infty$. Since $N$ was arbitrary, this is precisely the statement that $I(v)$ has the asymptotic expansion

$$
I(v) \approx \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{g^{(k)}(0)}{x^{k+1}}
$$

as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you, Antonio Vargas. I tried the v transformation earlier but did not proceed with the binomial expansion. The singularity at $v=1$ however prevents the direct application of Watson's lemma. I have modified your answer with an integration by parts to rid the singularity there. But it seems not to match the other answer though. I have not figured out why.

Comment: @Hans Watson's lemma has no issue with the singularity at $v=1$. To apply it to an integral of the form $\int_0^1 e^{-xv} g(v)\,dv$, Watson's lemma only requires (for example) $g(v)$ to be to be analytic at $v=0$ and for $\int_0^1 |g(v)|\,dv$ to exist. See the proof of Watson's lemma on the wikipedia page (which I wrote). I have reverted the edits you made to my answer. It does match the other answer (I double checked in Mathematica), so I'm not sure where you're going wrong.

Comment: Hmm, it's been a while since I wrote that proof, but in rereading it now it looks like it doesn't quite apply to the case in question. It can be modified to work on this case, however.

Comment: @Hans I've added a proof of Watson's lemma (only slightly modified from the one I linked) which applies directly to this specific question.

Comment: It looks good. Maybe you can incorporate your current more general proof into the Wikipedia article. Also, do you see why the integration by parts approach I took did not give the right answer?

Comment: I have reverted your *new* edit, which replaces $\approx$ with the $\sim$ symbol. **Please stop modifying my answer.** I use $\approx$ for asymptotic expansions - this is the notation I wish to proliferate in my answers here. Also, this proof is not more general, it is just *different*. It does not apply to some cases which the proof I wrote for the wikipedia article does.

Comment: I will note that the *statement* of Watson's lemma on the wikipedia article *does* include the case in which this problem lies.

Comment: I am sorry. You used $\sim$ in your wikipedia article. $\sim$ is the usual symbol for asymptotics whereas $\approx$ usually means numerical approximation. You are right the proofs are different since the original wikipedia proof applies to exponentially increasing function whereas your current one will not work in that case.

Comment: True, I used $\sim$ on wikipedia to make it consistent with wikipedia's notation in their [asymptotic expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion) article, but in my own work I use $\approx$ to follow the style of [de Bruijn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolaas_Govert_de_Bruijn).

Answer (score 5):

The integral can be solved in closed form in terms of the Dawson function.
$$f(x)=F(\sqrt{x})/\sqrt{x} \sim \frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{4x^2}+\frac{3}{8x^3} +\ldots$$
Mathematica was used to perform the asymptotic expansion for $x \to \infty.$